# How to change the playback speed (video speed) in Photos app on macOS?

Tags: photos, video

Is there a way to change the video playback rate for videos viewed in Photos app on macOS?

Comment: I think you'd need to change the actual frame rate of the video.

Comment: @X_841 hmm.. I definitely don't want to make any permanent changes to the video file, only view it at a higher speed

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but I fear there is no way to achieve that in the stock macOS photos App.